How to install numpy for Python 2.7 on EC2 ubuntu 22.04?
I have the need to use the older python 2.7 with numpy for a Spark project on EC2 ubuntu 22.04. These were what I did ...
 sudo apt update
 sudo apt install python2.7
 sudo apt-get install python-numpy

The last step got an error "E: Unable to locate package python-numpy".
Any suggestions on to fix the problem?

Packages installed via apt that come from Ubuntu's official repositories are more secure than pip packages that come from PyPI, which is a public repository where anyone can upload packages. To install the python-numpy package from Ubuntu 20.04 in Ubuntu 22.04 open the terminal and type:
sudo apt update
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/python-numpy/python-numpy_1.16.5-2ubuntu7_amd64.deb  
sudo mkdir /tmp
sudo cp /home/ubuntu/python-numpy_1.16.5-2ubuntu7_amd64.deb /tmp/
cd /tmp
sudo apt install ./python-numpy_1.16.5-2ubuntu7_amd64.deb


Thank you. I will try that too.

I got the following at the apt install step ... N: Download is performed unsandboxed as root as file '/home/ubuntu/python-numpy_1.16.5-2ubuntu7_amd64.deb' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied).

@dotnetnetdot You don't have permissions to use apt to install a .deb file in your current directory, so try moving it to a new directory named /tmp. I edited my answer with the appropriate commands.

Thank you so much. Now it works. Appreciate the help.

Instead of using numpy from the Ubuntu repos - where it is obviously not included any more in Ubuntu 22.04 - you can install first pip via the package python-pip and then install via pip numpy.
Remember that the numpy project dropped the support for Python 2.7 for numpy 1.7 and newer, thus the highest version you can install is 1.16.6.
So the steps for the installation are:
sudo apt-get install python-pip
pip2 install numpy==1.16.6  #run the command with sudo in case you need a system-wide installation

Please remember that neither Python 2.7 nor numpy 1.16.6 are supported any more, thus there will be not more bug fix releases and any possibly existing vulnerabilities will not be fixed. The support for numpy 1.16.6 was dropped on Jan 1st 2020. The same applies to pip installed from Ubuntu's sources, as the pip project dropped the support for Python 2 as well. pip 20.3, which is the version included in the Ubuntu sources, is the highest version which still support Python 2.

Thank you so much. When I submitted the 2nd command "sudo pip install numpy==1.16.6", I got an error message saying "sudo: pip: command not found",

Thanks for the feedback. The correct call must be pip2 install .... I edited my answer making this correction.

That worked. Thank you so much for your help. Really appreciate it.
